# Protecting routes in Nextjs 13(AppRouter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js

i'm creating an app using Next.js (app router) on the front-end and Express.js with Passport.js using the local strategy with sessions on the back-end.

I already have the routes /login, /logout, and /user configured on the back-end to verify authentication. I believe the back-end part is all set up as it should be.

My difficulty lies more specifically with the Next.js part. I'm not exactly sure how to configure protected routes in my application. I have an AuthProvider that contains functions for login, logout, and fetchUser, and I placed this AuthProvider in my RootLayout. I'll try to upload some code here so you can understand better what i did.

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Htw4.png)

My AuthProvider.tsx is looking like this:

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

type User = Record<string, unknown> | null;

interface AuthContextType {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  user: User;
  login: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  isLoading: boolean;
  logout: () => Promise<void>;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: null,
  login: async () => {},
  isLoading: true,
  logout: async () => {}
});


function AuthProvider({ children }: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  const fetchUser = async () => {
    console.log("user fetched");
    
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/user", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const data = await response.json();
      setUser(data);
    } else {
      setUser(null);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      credentials: "include",
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      await fetchUser();
      router.push("/profile");
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    console.log("Sessão destruída");
    await fetch("http://localhost:4000/logout", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
    });
    
    setUser(null);
    router.push('/');
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated: !!user, user, login, isLoading, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export { AuthProvider };
```

My RootLayout is like this:

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { AuthProvider } from "./auth/AuthProvider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="pt-BR">
      <AuthProvider>
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </AuthProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

However, I'm unsure how to protect specific routes, like /profile. One idea I had was simply importing the useAuth() hook there and checking if the user is authenticated. If not, it would redirect the user to the login page. However, to achieve this, I would need to turn the profile page into a client component, and I don't think it's a good practice to turn an entire page into a client component, right? But I would have to do that to import the useAuth() hook, and I'm running out of ideas. Most of the solutions I find online are for the old page structure and don't seem to fit well with my code. Anyway, does anyone have something to say about this situation? Thank you.

Comment: I been having the similar problem. I been playing around with the idea of creating a singleton and seeing I can pass that around. I haven’t tried it yet but will get back to you later